# Reload/Update include PHP file in jquery on wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, widget

This issue is resolved. My friend helped me here is the working code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(jQuery.get("<?php
    $url = plugin_dir_url( $file ); 
    echo plugins_url( 'update.php' , __FILE__ ); ?>", function(responseData) {
      jQuery("#cur_pos").html(responseData);
    }), 1000 * 300);

    </script>
<div id="cur_pos">

</div>
```

I want to reload a php file every so often to update a widget im making for wordpress.

My code thus for ive hacked together doesn't seem to work. it will work when i use the simple include but wont refresh of course. What am I missing?

```
<script type="Javascript">
    // reload php
    if(!jQuery && $) {
    var jQuery = $;
    }

    function updatePos(){
    UpdateInSeconds = 30;
    jQuery('#cur_pos').load('<?php
    $url = plugin_dir_url( $file ); 
    echo plugins_url( 'update.php' , __FILE__ ); ?>');
    setTimeout("updatePos();",UpdateInSeconds*1000) ;
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    updatePos();
    });
    </script>


    <div id="cur_pos">

    </div>
```

This is the output:

```
     <script type="Javascript">
        // reload php
        if(!jQuery && $) {
        var jQuery = $;
        }

        function updatePos(){
        UpdateInSeconds = 30;
        jQuery('#cur_pos').load('http://www.thepuzzycat.com/wp-content/plugins/ArduinoStats/update.php');
        setTimeout("updatePos();",UpdateInSeconds*1000) ;
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        updatePos();
        });
        </script>
<div id="cur_pos">

</div>
```

Comment: Missing `#` => `jQuery("cur_pos")`.

Comment: Still didnt work. i revised it a bit but stil doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(jQuery.get("http://www.thepuzzycat.com/wp-content/plugins/ArduinoStats/update.php", function(responseData) {
    jQuery("#cur_pos").html(responseData);
}), 1000 * 300);
```

It's not the best solution for performance and other aspects, but it does work and it's better than using a recursive function.